# Sony WH-1000XM3 are connected only in hands-free mode WIN11

Tags: audio, bluetooth

i got OS update to Win11 Pro. I'd like to connect my Sony WH-1000XM3 via bluetooth. I made standard connection process but my audio quality is bad. On win10 i could easiely switch between stereo/hands-free mode to solve this. I cant find any solution to this. In new bluetooth setting i can see my headphones connected with "Connected voice" message. I tried multiple solutions on web:
Drivers reinstall - no help. 
Disable mic input device from headphones - no help
Advanced settings -> allow private acces from apps in unchecked - no help. 
Devices and printers ->Sony WH-1000XM3 properties -> services -> unchecked Hands-Free or i tried uncheck everything except Audio Sink, Remote control - on this case i am not able to use my headphones at all, it is connected in bluetooth settings but there is no option to use them in new/old sound settings
Thanks for help

Comment: Hey PatoS, have you been able to spot the cause of the problem?
Have same issue here

Answer (score 0):

Stuck with the same "Hands-free" profile on Windows 11 upon switching between two PCs.

Prior "Remove device" helped to pair it properly.

After that "Headphones" profile was recognized and "Connected voice, music" appeared next to WH-1000XM2:
[Resolved issue appears like that in Settings app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8u0A.png)